# Chrome overflow:auto scrolls body when using trackpad

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a fixed position div with `overflow:auto`. On Chrome OSX, when I scroll within the div, after reaching the end, the body begins scrolling.

Here's a sample: http://codepen.io/DJWard/full/a86416eab5d83da6f8eca03c80c570f8/

This behavior doesn't happen in Firefox.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: I didn't. I updated the pen with your solution. Setting the content div with `height: 100vh; overflow:auto;`

Is that what you are suggesting?